# Does cytoplasmic streaming exert a force on the cytoskeleton itself?

Tags: botany, organelle

In plant cells, cytoplasmic streaming is though to be driven by the force generated from active transport of myosin-cargo complexes along actin highways. Does this force also act on the actin filaments themselves? Does it contribute to the movemement of the cargo along these filaments?